# How to split up a function with multiple behaviors controlled by flags

Tags: python, api-design

I have been asked to add a feature to the following function:

```
def maybe_do_thing(x, y, z, really_do_thing):
  if really_do_thing:
    return f(x, y, z) # returns a list
  return []           # an empty list if we did nothing
```

Specifically, it should also be able to call `g(x, y, z)`, controlled by an additional flag. The obvious implementation is:

```
def maybe_do_things(x, y, z, do_f, do_g):
  results = []
  if do_f:
    results.extend(f(x, y, z))
  if do_g:
    results.extend(g(x, y)) # g needs slightly different params
  return results
```

To be clear, any subset of f and g may be called: both, neither, or just one, according to the two separate flags. f and g are conceptually related, so it sorta makes sense to group them together like this, but it feels quite unsatisfying to me: really `maybe_do_things` is just multiple functions masquerading as one function by means of multiple flags.

I'm fairly sure this is an antipattern, but I don't know what it's called or what the right pattern is to fix it. I feel like I ought to be able to split it into multiple self-sufficient functions in a way that is still as convenient to call as the composite function, or somehow clean up the API of the composite function so that it's not just one big blob.

Just inlining `maybe_do_things` at each call site is not very good: it might be good if callers know ahead of time which of f and g will be performed, but both of those are determined at runtime. So, every caller would need the full current function body, as well as local definitions representing the now-repeated x/y/z variables.

I don't think many more features will be added to this function in the future, so at least I don't have to worry about the parameter list exploding. Maybe my "obvious" implementation is actually the best compromise?

Comment: If the caller has enough information to know whether to pass `do_f` or `do_g`, they have enough information to just call the right one themselves. It's a bit hard to analyze this without knowing more about these flags and where/how the functions are called. But one possibility is instead of thinking of `really_do_thing` as a "flag" saying whether to call `f`, call that argument `context` or the like. Then each call site passes a "context" that contains all the necessary information to decide what to actually do. Even better might be to make the context an object that has f, g, etc. as methods.

Comment: Yes, they have enough information that they could call the right functions themselves. But it's much easier to just pass one boolean argument to the `maybe_do_things` function, eg `maybe_do_things(..., should_i_do_f())`, than to write the whole of `if should_i_do_f(): f(x, y, z)`, if `f` is a complicated thing to do.

Comment: For future useres perusing here, this is related to the code smell "Flag Argument" see: https://luzkan.github.io/smells/flag-argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what is the reason for the function `maybe_do_things` instead of calling `f(x,y,z)` or `g(x,y,z)` if the caller already knows which one to call before hand, but one solution could be to implement the decision-making code inside `maybe_do_things` as a function with 4 possible outcomes: neither, both, f or g like so:

```
def maybe_do_things(x,y,z, problem):
    results = []
    decision = decide(problem)
    if decision == 'both':
        return results.extend(f(x,y,z)+g(x,y))
    elif decision == 'neither':
        return results
    elif decision == 'f':
        return results.extend(f(x,y,z))
    elif decidion == 'g':
        return results.extend(g(x,y))
```

Answer (score -1):

you could count how many arg for each function.

```
def maybe_do_thing(funcs, *args):
  res = []
  for func in funcs:
    num_arg = func.func_code.co_argcount
    new_arg = args[:num_arg]
    res.append(func(*new_arg))
  return res

def print_f(string):
  return string + 'a'

def print_f2(string, string2):
  return string + 'a' + string2

print maybe_do_thing([print_f, print_f2], 'd', 'c')

['da', 'dac']
```